# How to reduce cache_imagesizes queries in Typo3 4.5

Tags: typo3, tt-news, typo3-4.5

We have an old Typo3 `4.5` application running very slowly on any server. Using blackfire.io and general debugging we are trying to figure out the bottleneck and whether we can alleviate some of the processing time.

The application uses the `tt_news` extension on various pages on the website. The index page has a lot of different `tt_news` modules, displaying entries for various categories and the like. All these entries also usually have a picture associated with them.

One of the major bottlenecks is the large number of SQL queries executed by Typo3. Particularly taxing is the following query, which is executed **247 times** (!) on the start page:

```
SELECT ... FROM cache_imagesizes WHERE md5filename = ? limit ?
```

So far I wasn't able to find any ressource on how to alleviate this or if it is even possible. I think that the `tt_news` extension is just extremely inefficient.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set an `index` on `md5filename`. As this is a hash column, an index should be not more than five characters.

247 queries means that you have 247 pictures that are taken into account in order to render the front page. If you do not display that many pictures, try to reduce the data taking into account by setting limits in the plugins and in the rendering.

Comment: `md5filename` already has an index, though I haven't checked its length yet. Typo3 already creates the table this way. Also regarding the queries: `tt_news` seems to be an extremely inefficient plugin. Yes, it processes 247 images or rather news entries - however the page in question doesn't even display that many entries. It always seems load **all** the entries from the database, regardless of the configured limits.

Comment: That is a problem of *your* ``tt_news`` configuration. ``tt_news`` works fine on pages with more than 10000 news entries.